# Replace a string at particular row and column

Tags: awk, sed

I have a input file with mxn matrix. I need to replace xth row, yth column string with a new string. How can do this in linux ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, it is always good to show sample Input and expected sample output with all your conditions along with what you have tried too in CODE TAGS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't given the example of sample Input and expected output so I am considering let's say following is the Input_file and we want to change 2nd row's 3rd column so variable in `awk` row defines that variable named column defines the column where you want to make changes, you could set it as per your need.

```
cat Input_file
1 2 3 4
2 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
3 4 5 6
```

Then following code may help you on same:

```
 awk -v row=2 -v column=3 -v new_string="some_value" 'NR==row{sub(/.*/,new_string,$column)} 1'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
1 2 3 4
2 4 some_value 6
4 5 6 7
3 4 5 6
```